# Can I execute Javascript mit PhpBrowser in Acceptance Tests in Codeception?

Tags: javascript, codeception

I want to do something like this:

```
$I->amOnPage('<URL>');
$I->executeJS('alert("yay!")'); // executeJS does not exist, I am looking for something like it
```

From what I googled, I can do it with *WebDriver*, but is it also possible with *PhpBrowser*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is impossible with PhpBrowser.